# How to model one-to-one relationships in AngularJS with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have a `companies` collection with a `country_id` field that refers to `_id`in a `countries` collection.

`Companies` as follow:

```
{
    name: "acme",
    address: "zossener straße 123",
    postalCode: "10961",
    city: "berlin",
    country_id: "56d58d68ab68b5cf3f72788e"
}
```

`Countries` as follow:

```
{
    _id: "56d58d68ab68b5cf3f72788e",
    name: "Germany"
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is to replace the `country_id` of `Companies` to `Countries.name`. So for each company I want the country name, not the country ID. I'm using Restangular. My controller:

```
// creates a Restangular object of the 'companies' endpoint for later use
var Companies = Restangular.all('companies');

// for later pushing the countries
$scope.allCompanies = [];

// queries companies collection
Companies.getList().then(function(companies) {
  $scope.companies = companies;

  // iterates each company to get the country name
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.companies.length; i++) {
    // prepares temp object to be pushed to $scope.allCompanies
    var buffer = {
      name: $scope.companies[i].name,
      address: $scope.companies[i].address,
      postalCode: $scope.companies[i].postalCode,
      city: $scope.companies[i].city,
      countryId: $scope.companies[i].country_id
    };

    // queries countries collection passing country_id
    var Country = Restangular.one('countries', $scope.companies[i].country_id);

    Country.get().then(function(country) {
      // sets country name for temp object based on country_id
      buffer.country = country.name;

      // pushes buffer to $scope.allCompanies
      $scope.allCompanies.push(buffer);
    });
  };
```

When running, `$scope.allCompanies` shows all companies with only one country, which is the last country assigned to `buffer`. I assume that there's something wrong with promises, but not sure. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the logic that retrieves the country in a function. This way, the function keeps the correct reference of `buffer` without being affected by the change of `i`:

```
// creates a Restangular object of the 'companies' endpoint for later use
var Companies = Restangular.all('companies');

// for later pushing the countries
$scope.allCompanies = [];

// queries companies collection
Companies.getList().then(function(companies) {
  $scope.companies = companies;
   function setCountryName(buffer){

    // queries countries collection passing country_id
    var Country = Restangular.one('countries', buffer.countryId);

    Country.get().then(function(country) {
      // sets country name for temp object based on country_id
      buffer.country = country.name;
    });
    return buffer;
   }

  // iterates each company to get the country name
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.companies.length; i++) {
    // prepares temp object to be pushed to $scope.allCompanies
    var buffer = {
      name: $scope.companies[i].name,
      address: $scope.companies[i].address,
      postalCode: $scope.companies[i].postalCode,
      city: $scope.companies[i].city,
      countryId: $scope.companies[i].country_id
    };

      // pushes buffer to $scope.allCompanies
      $scope.allCompanies.push(setCountryName(buffer));
  };
```

Comment: works perfectly! can you explain a bit more why my code was not working? I'm not 100% clear on this.

Comment: Your loop was changing the value of `i` before the request to `countries` was completed (since it is asynchronous). This made that the reference of `buffer` changed before the answer, and the promise would then update a different `buffer` variable. This made funny things to the result. By making the code invoking `countries` keep a reference you can avoid this.